# Black Screen while Gaming, But Sound still working

Tags: power, gpu, black-screen-of-death

While gaming my 2 monitors go black with the **no signal** message and I hear the Windows disconnect sound like when you unplug an USB. The thing is that the sound of the game is still running and I am able to speak with my friends on TeamSpeak.

Here is the list of games where this happen:

- Counter Strike : Global Offensive
- Rust
- Crysis 3
- Rainbow Six : Siege

I can't ALT+TAB nor CTRL+ALT+DELETE

My setup:

- **OS** - Windows 10 Pro x64
- **CPU** - Intel i5-4690
- **Mainboard** - ASUSTeK MAXIMUS VII HERO
- **GPU** - ASUS GTX 780 STRIX
- **RAM** - 2x DDR3 4GB
- **PSU** - Corsair GS800W
- **Storage** - 250GB
- **SSD** - 1TB HDD
- **Monitors** - 1080p60hz(DVI) - 1440p 144hz(Display Port)

Here are the thing I tried out.

- Reinstall Windows
- Changed GPU to another PCI Slot
- Used older GPU Drivers
- Tried running on only 1 monitor
- After changing to an older Driver I let FurMark run for like 30 min with no crash
- Unplug monitor cable and plug it back while the screen is black
- **Tried with a brand new GTX 980 and it still crashes**

What kind of tests could I do to find what piece of hardware is causing this issue?

**NOTE: My last GPU broke(not going over 10 FPS while gaming)**

Comment: One thing I had happen when I got windows 10 up and running: notifications would attempt to steal focus from full-screen games, and I would be locked out at a black screen and alt-tab/ctrl+alt+delete wouldn't work. I had to go into the task manager when the game wasn't running and set it up to "always be on top." It always was before, but perhaps the default is now "not always on top." Second: whenever Windows 10 want you to schedule a restart, it will steal focus and force a modal dialog. Maybe the audio is a "VPU recover" or perhaps it is some other notification (loose usb chord etc)

Comment: Yorik Thx for the reply. The thing is my monitors go off. You know when the monitor has no signal ,the led of the monitor goes from blue/green to amber.

Comment: Have you tried limiting the refresh rate to 60Hz down from 144Hz?

Comment: It doesn't matter what Monitor I use it still happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the power supply was causing my GPU to run out of power. This caused the monitors to disconnect from the GPU.